# Does an infinite axiom system exist for a finitely axiomatizable theory in first order logic?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, model-theory

What I'm trying to find:

A concrete example in predicate logic with the following characteristics:

1. An infinite system of axioms for a finitely axiomatizable theory.
2. Any finite subset of the infinite axiom system should no longer axiomatize the theory.

My first intuition was to recursivly define a infinite set of formulas which axiomatize the theory, but I didn't manage to build any examples myself.
So I'm not sure if such a axiomatic system is even possible

Comment: Please include some more context in your question, such as where you got it or what you have tried.

Comment: Can'1 you just add infinitely many tautologous sentences?

Comment: Add $\forall x (x = x)$, $\forall xy (x =x \land y = y$, $\forall xyz(x = x \land y = y \land z = z)$, etc?

Comment: Apologies for the badly written Question, English is not my first Language and I'm having trouble correctly phrasing what I'm after.

 yes @Bram28 that would be a viable solution to how I phrased the Question.


What I really want is:

1. An infinite System of Axioms for a finitely axiomatizable theorem.
2. Any finite subset of the infinite axiom system should no longer axiomatize the theorem.

Sorry again, and thank you for taking your time to answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is impossible, by the compactness theorem. See my answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3814809/7062

Comment: I didn't close the question as a duplicate because the question asked is different, even if the answer is the same. If others (or a moderator) disagree, feel free to mark this as a duplicate!

Comment: Thank you for your answer! A quick follow up question: this means there is no axiomatic system for a basic elementary class which meets the characteristics mentioned in my original question?

Comment: Generally the criterion for duplicates is based on answers, not questions.  (The message when a question is marked as a duplicate is not "This question was asked here:" but "This question has an answer here".)  If it's not completely obvious how the linked duplicate answers a question, you can briefly explain that in a comment.  (And if the explanation is too long for a comment, then probably you want to write an answer instead of just marking it as a duplicate.)

Comment: That said, the specific question you picked here is probably not the best choice of a duplicate for this question.  I'm sure something very close to this exact question has been asked several times before.

Comment: @EricWofsey Well, if you can find a better duplicate - as I said, feel free to mark it.

Comment: Yeah, I'm looking for one now.  It actually seems surprisingly hard to find...maybe I'm just not searching for the right phrases.

Comment: @EricWofsey I extensively tried to search for a answer to my question before posting, but couldn't find any. Maybe it was my language barrier, or I didn't know how to phrase it with the right terminology.

Comment: @how_is_this_supposed_to_run I don't see how your follow up question differs from your original question. In case it's not clear: There is no theory $T$ satisfying conditions 1 and 2 in your question.

Comment: @AlexKruckman okay that clears it up, thanks!

Comment: Hmmm, it seems I may have just been wrong.  Lots of questions with answers that use this idea have been asked but I actually can't find one that is really on the nose.